# Why are mapped drives available only with admin rights?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, mapped-drive

I am using Windows 10 pro, version 1607, build 14393.321 the latest available at this date. Some network drives are mapped with domain group policy and logon scripts.

Opening an elevated command prompt **NET USE** correctly displays the mapped drive.

On the contrary opening a command prompt with user rights **NET USE** doesn't show the mapped drive.

The user I made the test with is in the local administrator group.

I know about **EnableLinkedConnections** registry key, I tried it but it doesn't work. Also, because it solves exactly the opposite problem, mapped drives which are not available with elevated rights.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I would say, something prevents the normal user from getting its drive mappings. Do they show up in explorer?

Comment: If the user is a local administrator the network drives mapped with logon scripts are only  visible in an elevated context. If the user is not a local administrator the mapped drives are correctly shown.

Comment: Mapped drives are mapped by user token. Administrators have two - a normal one and an elevated one. They are only available to the token that mapped them. Solution is to map the drive  for each token. You will have to set the registry key you mention to allow a drive to have multiple mappings.